# VScode extension webview origin

Tags: vscode-extensions, vscode-webview

I have built a vscode webview extension and i have deployed it on marketplace but my extension is not able to access the server what should the origin be and where to find it ?

i tried on local server to cosnole my origin and i got vscode-webview://1bp3t804jiq5n4kiv5embq7oq2tc02jcogg3u7m8vlo94v7dm990
but it will be different for all users becoz i tried to see my other laptop origin it was different from above so i built a regex to check :
const vscodeOriginPattern = /^vscode-webview://[a-zA-Z0-9-]+$/;
but on my local it's working but on production server still my vscode extension is not able to access my server

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.